# How to download "RDL report files" from SQL Report server 2008 programatically

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

How can I download the "RDL report files" from SQL Report Server 2008 programatically (vb.net).

I just need to download all reports and upload all back in one click event. Is this possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? What does this accomplish? Are you editing the files programmatically then pushing them back up to the database?

Comment: Also, have you tried anything or found any indication that this is possible in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Several times, I have used a program called SSRSExtractor (open source).  It is available on CodeProject.com  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339744/SSRS-Downloading-RDL-Files

Answer (score 0):

I also had some code before to download reports from ssrs server

```
public void SaveAdhocReportsToFile()
    {
        string inputPath = "Reports";
        string outPutDir = "D:\\Reports\\";
        ExportListItemToFiles("/" + inputPath, ".rdl", outPutDir, ItemType.Report);
    }

private void ExportListItemToFiles(string inputPath, string fileExtension, string outPutFolder, string itemType)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exporting " + itemType + " from SSRS - folder " + inputPath + " to " + outPutFolder);

            string outPutFile = string.Empty;
            List<CatalogItem> items = ReportService.ListChildren(inputPath, false).Where(x => x.TypeName == itemType).ToList();


            foreach (CatalogItem item in items)
            {
                byte[] rpt_def = null;
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                rpt_def = ReportService.GetItemDefinition(item.Path);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rpt_def);

                outPutFile = string.Format(@"{0}{1}" + fileExtension, outPutFolder, item.Name);

                if (File.Exists(outPutFile))
                    File.Delete(outPutFile);

                doc.Load(stream);
                doc.Save(outPutFile);
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

You can refer to ReportingService2010 Methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010_methods%28v=sql.120%29.aspx